# Why is controller not defined? Error: Undefined index: controller

Tags: php, laravel, controller

I'm trying out Laravel 5 for the first time, and I have run into a problem early on. If someone could explain it to me i'd be very grateful.

The first lines of my index.php script are as follows:

```
// Define path to data folder
define('DATA_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/data'));

//include our models
include_once 'models/TodoItem.php';


try {
    //get all of the parameters in the POST/GET request
    $params = $_REQUEST;

    //get the controller and format it correctly so the first
    //letter is always capitalized
    $controller = ucfirst(strtolower($params['controller']));

    //get the action and format it correctly so all the
    //letters are not capitalized, and append 'Action'
    $action = strtolower($params['action']).'Action';
...
```

This throws the following exceptions when run:

**( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: controller in /index.php on line 15
   Call Stack**

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: action in /index.php on line 19
   Call Stack

{"success":false,"errormsg":"Controller is invalid."}

Could someone explain how I set up $controller and $action correctly? Please excuse my noobness, I'm trying to learn a framework for the first time!

Comment: can you please do `print_r($params)` and edit the answer

Comment: $params is simply an empty array at this point. It returns "Array( )" .

Comment: @Leon if your $params array is empty, then you can't access $params['controller']. You are trying to access something that doesn't exist!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I fixed my problem. This is going to sound really stupid, but to a framework / MVC noob it was confusing...

I had neglected to create a controller layer! In fact i had, but hadn't referenced it correctly.

Now i have a script in a folder called 'controllers' which constructs an array from $params, ie whatever I send it in the url/post method. And it all works! Here is my basic controller function:

```
class Todo
{
  private $_params;

  public function __construct($params)
  {
    $this->_params = $params;
  }

  public function createAction()
  {
    // create a todo item
    $todo = new TodoItem();
    $todo->title = $this->_params['title'];
    $todo->description = $this->_params['description'];
    $todo->due_date = $this ->_params['due_date'];
    $todo->is_done = 'false';

    //pass the user's username and password to authenticate the user
    $todo->save($this->_params['username'], $this->_params['userpass']);

    //return the todo item in array format
    return $todo->toArray();
  }
```

Separate out your models and controllers, people! Thanks for your time and patience for those who commented.

Answer (score 1):

Can you confirm your that your `$params` indexes match your request names? Also, could you provide the code where you build your view for the request?

Comment: Please add this as a comment to the question.

Comment: I need 50+ rep to do that.. I think?